# V4L2 devices show up in in pipewire. How do I remove them?

Tags: pipewire, v4l2loopback

Demonstrative image [image: qpwgraph]

I have every video device duplicated in PipeWire due to v4l2. I cannot recall what I did years ago to make them appear.

How can I remove these duplicate devices?